# Awk for multiple patterns for variable length file

Tags: awk

I am trying to search multiple patterns where I would the start and end of the first few characters. This works for a single pattern.

```
awk '/test_pattern/ { match($0, /test_pattern/); print substr($0, RSTART - 10, RLENGTH + 20);' file
```

How do I do for multiple patterns? The file is not based on columns but delimiters. Thank you.

Here is an example for one row.

```
X;Y;AC=1;AN=31388;AF=3.18593e-05;0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|AC_CAT=4.5;X;X;X;X;AC_DOG=4.6; X;X;X;AC_PUT=5.4
```

I am trying to get everything that begins with AC, AF and AN. At the same time, I want the first two columns if possible.

Expected output:

```
X     Y    AC=1    AF=3.18593e-05  AC_CAT=4.5   AC_DOG=4.6   AC_PUT=5.4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with related expected output.

Comment: Just added. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, just updated it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you left the `AN=` column out of your expected output by accident since you said in  your question `I am trying to get everything that begins with AC, AF and AN` and you actually just want all of the `name=value` columns printed. If so:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[;|]"; OFS="\t" }
{
    printf "%s%s%s", $1, OFS, $2
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /=/) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
X       Y       AC=1    AN=31388        AF=3.18593e-05  AC_CAT=4.5      AC_DOG=4.6      AC_PUT=5.4
```

Comment: Actually, I want all the fields that starts with AC, AN and AF to be printed...Is that possible?

Comment: That;s exactly what you got. Look at the output - all fields start with AC, AN, and AF.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="A[CFN][A-Z_]*=[0-9.]+"} {for(i =1; i<=NF;i++) print $i" "}' d
```